# Were the correct enharmonics used here?

Tags: sheet-music, accidentals, enharmonics

I’m still a bit new to properly writing out sheet music, so I was wondering if the last few measures (see image below) were written out correctly. If they aren’t, then which ones are wrong and why (and honestly if they’re right it’d be nice to know why too, as I’m mostly guessing when I write out enharmonics).

[image: The section in question]

Comment: It looks good to me, but I don't have time at the moment to write up an explanation.  I'm sure someone else will.

Comment: Looks very fine to me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks quite reasonable to me.  Each of the chords that would use enharmonics is notated in flats, and each of these chords seems to "slide" down to the final chord.

The chord at the beginning of 58 is an F-flat major seventh, followed by a D-flat minor seventh; at 59 we hear a G-flat major with an added ninth.

Beginning in 57, we have a sort of a **V  bVI  iv  bVII** progression.  Given that the altered chords **bVI, iv,** and **bVII** are all created by lowering the chords of the prevailing scale, the use of flats makes sense.

Another way to think about it (if your head is swirling to consider F-flat and C-flat) is to move the progression into C major for discussion.

**V  bVI  iv  bVII** would be notated as **G Ab Fmin Bb**. I think most musicians would agree that the use of flats would be simpler than sharps here.  Also, the flat usage "tells" the singers that their pitches are going to have a tendency to resolve down, which they do.  Nice tag!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! I wish I could say I wrote the tag, but it’s actually from an arrangement of “Tonight, Tonight” from West Side Story. I can’t remember the arranger off the top of my head but I know I originally heard it from a recording by the Ringmasters. Again, thanks for the response!